# how can i save a (e.x. !lang en) in to a json file for the bot to use diff commands for that lang

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js, fs

So im trying to make code for the bot to save like !lang en or something like that in to a json file so

(btw im new to discord bot making)

```
client.on('message' message => {
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('!lang'){
if (args[1]) = 'en' {
fs.save.en.json(message.guild.id)
} else if (args[1]) = 'sp' {
fs.save.sp.json(message.guild.id)
}
}
});
```

so ye that how i think the code will look like but i dont know how to make it work
and also i use a command handler so i want to add it so like

```
if (sp.json(message.guild.id)) {
} else return;
```

so the diff lang only works for that server pls help make the code work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you are saving the languages by, (Users, Guilds, Roles?), so the way you can do this is make sure you have your JSON file like this:

```js
{
"Placeholder": {
"lang": "en"
}
}
```

Then, check if the user, role or guild is not already saved, you can do this to save it:

```js
var langs = require('./langs.json') //if your json file was named langs
const fs = require('fs');
client.on("message", msg => {
if(!langs['U'+msg.author.id]) {
langs['U'+msg.author.id] = "en";

fs.writeFile('./langs.json', JSON.stringify(langs), err => {
if(err) throw err;
console.log('User saved successfully');
})
}
})
```

And you can change that with `guildCreate` to make it for the guild, `guildMemberAdd` to save them as soon as they join, and more!
That’s all I have for you right now.